# Preventing reference re-use during deepcopy

Tags: python, list, deep-copy, memoization

Consider the following example:

```
from copy import deepcopy

item = [0]
orig = [item, item]
copy = deepcopy(orig)

orig[0][0] = 1
print(f"{orig=} {copy=}")

copy[0][0] = 2
print(f"{orig=} {copy=}")
```

The first `print` outputs what I would expect because the same reference is duplicated in the list.

```
orig=[[1], [1]] copy=[[0], [0]]
```

However, the second `print` surprised me.

```
orig=[[1], [1]] copy=[[2], [2]]
```

I would have expected the `deepcopy` to end up with two independent references inside the `copy` list. Instead it maintains the property of a single list reference duplicated. I'm guessing that's alluded to in this part of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

I see that the `deepcopy` function has a `memo` argument. Is there anything interesting that could be done with this argument to prevent the duplicated reference, such that the final output would become:

```
orig=[[1], [1]] copy=[[2], [0]]
```

Comment: Anyway, this behavior is implied by the docs, particularly: "Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist with shallow copy operations...Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, such as data which is intended to be shared between copies."

Comment: It would perhaps be better if you elaborate on you actual use-case. `deepcopy` is a convenience, I personally never use it. Most of the code I tend to write wouldn't require it, but if you really just needed to copy a nested list like this, I would pretty much always do `[sub.copy() for sub in mylist]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have a library that I give to users where some methods have parameters with JSON like structures (nested dicts, lists, etc). We do some mutation on the objects and return the mutated copy to the caller. So far I've been starting these types of calls with a `deepcopy`, but I found out some users have been getting more clever with how they construct the inputs, by using repeated references. After we do updates the to the copy, I discovered this interesting quirk. Only other thing I could think of quickly to avoid this would be a json.dump / json.load of the structure.

Comment: I mean, that sounds like a bad design, IMO. But you can trivially write a function that copies things... just what happens if your user inputs a data structure with reference cycles?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's a fair note about cycles, but these are supposed to look like valid JSON objects in my case, which shouldn't have cycles. I guess something like `copy = [[a for a in b] for b in orig]` would work here, but that becomes a lot of code when the structure is larger. If there's a simple approach to copying the structure without having to do that tedious work for each field, then I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your whole point is to copy data that could come from JSON, i.e. list, dict, string, numbers, bool, then you can trivially implement your own function:

```
def copy_jsonlike(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [copy_jsonlike(x) for x in data]
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        return {k: copy_jsonlike(v) for k,v in data.items()}
    else:
        return data
```

It has the added bonus of probably being faster than `copy.deepcopy`

Or, your original solution, `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` isn't a bad idea either.

Comment: Or if it's really round-trippable through JSON, just actually serialize and deserialize with `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` which is surprisingly fast (yay C extensions!), and definitionally can't preserve identity relationships across the serialization boundary.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, you are probably right, I'd bet `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` would be the fastest.

Comment: @flakes well, you'd have to handle set like `return {copy_jsonlike(x) for x in myset}`

Comment: I was thinking in my head `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` would be super slow, but I wasn't considering its a C extension. I guess I'm overthinking things!

Comment: @flakes `copy.deepcopy` is super slow!

Answer (score 1):

*Huh, seems like this was easier to do than I thought, but I'm 90% sure it's evil. If someone posts a better answer or explains why this is totally awful, I'll remove it.*

Implement a `dict` that only *pretends* to set a value. Then the example returns separate copies of the same reference.

```
class NoMemo(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return value
...
copy = deepcopy(orig, memo=NoMemo())
...
```

Prints:

```
orig=[[1], [1]] copy=[[0], [0]]
orig=[[1], [1]] copy=[[2], [0]]
```

Comment: I mean, this dict is totally broken, it doesn't set anything, so it will never get anything either. Now your deep copy operation may infinitely recourse if there are reference cycles

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can see the overlap in the question this got closed against.. I guess what I'm really getting at is how to prevent reference re-use during the `deepcopy`.  The broken dict is really just aiming to prevent it. Maybe the proper answer is use a different library.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? What's your actual use-case?

Comment: If you know there are no reference cycles, this is fine (it's what I immediately thought of, and it's a fine answer to the duplicate if you make sure to note the weakness). Sure, it's not as safe on arbitrary input, but that's what `RecursionError` is there to protect you against, and it does do precisely what you want: Make each object in the result unique (aside from immutable built-ins that can't even be shallow copied, but those don't need to be unique). In restricted use cases, it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @flakes: Minor note: Your `__setitem__` shouldn't be returning anything; `__setitem__`'s protocol doesn't expect or use a return value of any kind. The body of the method can just be `pass`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the feedback. The design totally makes more sense now when considering what deepcopy would do with cycles. I don't expect there to every be cycles in the structure. The data I'm working with is supposed to represent JSON like objects.